# How to store a date/time in sqlite (or something similar to a date)

Tags: python, html, database, sqlite, flask

I'm coding up a To-Do List website that asks the user for the task, the importance of the task (choose between two options: low, high) and the due date for said task. The plan is to show the user a list and place items that are of more importance or the due date is coming up for at the very front of the list.

I know the general gist of storing text inputs but am completely lost as to how to store something like a date. Even more so trying to understand how to set a countdown for the tasks.

I'm pretty new to coding as this is the first project that I have started, but any solutions or answers you give I will be grateful for.

[This is the page on the site where users give input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mN6P6.png)
[The /addrec route is the backend of the page that should be recieving user input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmShs.png)